# jQuery selector met now I want to remove the following span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been able to remove the word "Departments" using jQuery but I now want to remove one of the ">" characters that has been left behind in the HTML code inside some

```
<span> > </span>
```

where it puts out "Home > > Dog" I want to remove one of the ">"

I am unsure how to ask jQuery to ignore or remove the two lines of HTML above a selector?

```js
$(function() {
  $("a[title*='Categories']").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sitemappath">
  <span><a href="#" title="Home">Home</a></span><span> &gt; </span><span><a href="/allcategories.aspx" title="Categories">Departments</a></span><span> &gt; </span><span><a href="/dog/g7.aspx" title="Dog">Dog</a></span><span> &gt; </span><span><a href="/dog/food/g8.aspx" title="Food">Food</a></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to remove everything in span tag?

Comment: Please check answer here https://jsfiddle.net/89bc7xee/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your `.hide()` you can add `.parent().next("span").hide()`. It will remove the span after your `a[title*='Categories']`

```js
$(function() {
  $("a[title*='Categories']").hide().parent().next("span").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sitemappath">
  <span><a href="#" title="Home">Home</a></span><span> &gt; </span><span><a href="/allcategories.aspx" title="Categories">Departments</a></span><span> &gt; </span><span><a href="/dog/g7.aspx" title="Dog">Dog</a></span><span> &gt; </span><span><a href="http://dou9070.e-retailer.co.nz/dog/food/g8.aspx" title="Food">Food</a></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect!! Worked a charm. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Change the selector to target parent SPAN element, then use [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) to target immediately following sibling. with it use [`.addBack()`](http://api.jquery.com/addback/)

```js
$(function() {
  $("span:has(a[title*='Categories'])").next('span').addBack().hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sitemappath">
  <span><a href="#" title="Home">Home</a></span><span> &gt; </span><span><a href="/allcategories.aspx" title="Categories">Departments</a></span><span> &gt; </span><span><a href="/dog/g7.aspx" title="Dog">Dog</a></span><span> &gt; </span><span><a href="http://dou9070.e-retailer.co.nz/dog/food/g8.aspx" title="Food">Food</a></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this as your first line in `$(function(){` and it would work.

```
$("a[title*='Categories']").parent().next().hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select both `span` with `a` and next span element and hide them using.

```
 $("a[title*='Categories']").parent().next('span').addBack().hide();
```

```js
$("a[title*='Categories']").parent().next('span').addBack().hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sitemappath">
  <span><a href="#" title="Home">Home</a></span><span> &gt; </span><span><a href="/allcategories.aspx" title="Categories">Departments</a></span><span> &gt; </span><span><a href="/dog/g7.aspx" title="Dog">Dog</a></span><span> &gt; </span><span><a href="http://dou9070.e-retailer.co.nz/dog/food/g8.aspx" title="Food">Food</a></span>
</div>
```

Or you can use `:has()` selector to select `span` that has `a` element with specified attribute.

```
$("span:has(a[title*='Categories'])").next('span').addBack().hide();
```

```js
$("span:has(a[title*='Categories'])").next('span').addBack().hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sitemappath">
  <span><a href="#" title="Home">Home</a></span><span> &gt; </span><span><a href="/allcategories.aspx" title="Categories">Departments</a></span><span> &gt; </span><span><a href="/dog/g7.aspx" title="Dog">Dog</a></span><span> &gt; </span><span><a href="http://dou9070.e-retailer.co.nz/dog/food/g8.aspx" title="Food">Food</a></span>
</div>
```

Comment: andSelf() is depreciated